# Wandering Sets and Recurrent Transformations

Tags: ergodic-theory

I'd like to show that a measure preserving transformation $T:X\rightarrow X$ is recurrent iff it has no wandering sets of positive measure.

I'm working from the following definitions: a measurable set $W$ is wandering if for all $i,j\ge 0 ; i \neq j$ we have $T^{-i}(W) \cap T^{-j}(W) = \emptyset$, and a measure preserving transformation is recurrent if for every measurable set $A$ with nonzero measure, for almost all $x \in A$ there is some $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $T^n(x) \in A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you work with finite measure spaces.

Assume $T\colon X\to X$ recurrent. Let $W$ be a wandering element. Assume that $W$ has non-zero measure. Then $\mu\left(W\cap\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}T^{-n}W\right)=\mu(W)$, but the LHS is $0$ since $W$ is wandering.

Assume that $T\colon X\to X$ is not recurrent. Then there is $A$ of positive measure such that $\mu\left(A\cap\bigcup_{n\geqslant 1}T^{-n}A\right)<\mu(A)$. Define 
$$W:=A\cap\bigcap_{n\geqslant 1}T^{-n}\left(X\setminus A\right).$$
Then $W$ is a wandering set of positive measure.

Comment: I was not assuming that my measure space is finite. Does the statement still hold in that case?

Comment: Actually, it seems what I wrote doesn't assume that $X$ has finite measure.